# How to get which day from date in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this format of datetime in Python "2022-09-01 08:36:22", how can I get which weekday of it?

I also created this dictionary

day_of_week = {
1: "sunday",
2: "monday",
3: "tuesday",
4: "wednesday",
5: "thursday",
6: "friday",
7: "saturday"
}

to get number and convert it to corresponding day.

Update : september_2022["started_at"].dt.dayofweek

when I used this code I can get integer for corresponding day, but I want to create new column and assign it days of week.

september_2022["day_of_week"] = day_of_week[september_2022["started_at"].dt.dayofweek]

and get this error : unhashable type: 'Series'

Comment: Look at the first two lines in [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) table.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with new information, do not put it in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`dt.day_name`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html) for a vectorial conversion:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2022-09-01 08:36:22', '2022-09-03 08:36:22']})

pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.day_name()
```

output:

```
0    Thursday
1    Saturday
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the datetime library:

```
datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%A")
```